# Vb.Net Background Worker Updating UI Not Working

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I have a background worker that is supposed to be updating a `ToolStripLabel` with some status messages. However, the updating is not happening, but no errors are being thrown. Here's the code I am using:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker3_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker3.DoWork
        BackgroundWorker3.WorkerReportsProgress = True
         Dim Counter As Integer = 0

        Do Until BW1Running = False
            Counter = Counter + 1
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            Incident_Form.BackgroundWorker3.ReportProgress(Counter)
            If Counter >= 100 Then
                e.Result = False
                Return
            End If

        Loop

        If BW1Running = False Then
            Counter = 100
            Incident_Form.BackgroundWorker3.ReportProgress(Counter)
        End If
    End Sub


Private Sub BackgroundWorker3_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker3.ProgressChanged

    Me.ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString

End Sub
```

Nothing happens when the `ProgressChanged` is fired. I've debugged it and it'll print a line to the output window, but it will not update that label. Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling:

```
Incident_Form.BackgroundWorker3.ReportProgress()
```

instead of just:

```
BackgroundWorker3.ReportProgress()
```

Your `BackgroundWorker3_ProgressChanged` method is subscribed to the `ProgressChanged` event of the BackgroundWorker located in the **current form**, not in the `Incident_Form` form.

Remove `Incident_Form` from the beginning of the `BackgroundWorker3.ReportProgress()` calls and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks :) It's the little things!!! (Have to wait 5 mins before I can accept this as the answer, I'll come back and accept!)

Comment: @SilverShotBee : No problem! Maybe you should name your BackgroundWorkers so that you know which one you're using? :)

Comment: Maybe I should! I have fallen foul to the habit of just leaving the default name there, which is fine whilst its fresh in your mind, but after a few weeks it can be annoying trying to work out! I am quite good at leaving comments throughout the project though!